# Image para byte[]

Tags: c#, xamarin

Oi!
Estou usando o Xamarin.Forms para fazer um aplicativo. Então, eu preciso salvar imagens no Parse. Para fazer isso, eu preciso converter as imagens para byte[]. Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso ? Eu já procurei na internet mas nenhuma das soluções funcionou para mim. Na documentação do Parse tem um exemplo de como se faz com um arquivo texto :

```
  byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Working at Parse is great!");
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);
```

O Xamarin não me deixa usar o System.Drawning.Image, então a maioria dos métodos convencionais para c# não vão funcionar. Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso ?

Obrigado !

Answer (score 3):

Código

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif); //aqui voce troca o formato de arquivo a salvar
      return  ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente da forma abaixo.

Método responsável pela conversão de um objeto Image para byte[].

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Método responsável por fazer o inverso, ou seja, conversão de byte[] para Image.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Para maiores informações acesse o link a seguir:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv

Answer (score 2):

em c#

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\nomeimagem.jpg");
byte[] arr;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    arr =  ms.ToArray();
}
```

fonte : [Imagem para Byte](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)