# Duvidas em converter de Byte em Imagem em c# Está a apresentar um erro esquisito e pouco comum

Tags: c#

Estou tentar converter os bytes que se encontram num banco de dados para Imagem num *PictureBox* em C# 2012, mas quando chega numa determinada linha diz que o parâmetro é inválido, um erro anormal que nunca aconteceu antes, fiz um Debug e a única coisa que eu pude notar é que o parâmetro  *Funcionario.Foto* que trás os bytes do banco de dados tem apenas 13 *byte* e o erro ocorre no método que converte de *byte* para imagem.

Agradeceria que os programadores do fórum pudessem postar neste erro, já dei tudo que tenho e obtive êxitos, desde já agradeço.

Abaixo tenho os Métodos:

1º Método: Que permite apresentar os dados do banco de dados nos objectos do formulário através da classe BLL Código:

```
public Image ByteToImage(byte[] imageArray)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imageArray);
    }

        private void mCarregarCampos()
        {
            clsFuncionarioDTO Funcionario = new clsFuncionarioDTO();
            if (this.Text == "FUNCIONÁRIOS")
            {
                if (cbxCodFuncionario.Text != "")
                {  
                    bll.CarregarFuncionario(Funcionario, int.Parse(cbxCodFuncionario.Text));
                }
            }
            txtFuncionario.Text = Funcionario.Funcionario;
            txtEmail.Text = Funcionario.Email;
            txtSkype.Text = Funcionario.Skepe;
            ptbFoto.Image = null;
            if (Funcionario.Foto != null && Funcionario.Foto.Length > 0)
            {
                ptbFoto.Image = ByteToImage(Funcionario.Foto)
            }
   }
```

2º Metodo: que se encontra na classe BLL que contém a intrução SQL Código:

```
 public void CarregarFuncionario(clsFuncionarioDTO Funcionario,int comboBox)
        {
            string comando = "SELECT Funcionario,Email,Skype,Foto FROM tblFuncionarios WHERE  tblFuncionarios.CodFuncionario = " + comboBox + " ";
            string campo = "Funcionario"; 
            string campo1 = "Email";
            string campo2 = "Skype";
            string campo3 = "Foto";
            SqlDataReader seleccione = mMostrarDados(comando);
            while (seleccione.Read())
            {
                Funcionario.Funcionario = seleccione[campo].ToString();
                Funcionario.Email = seleccione[campo1].ToString();
                Funcionario.Skepe = seleccione[campo2]ToString(); 
                if (seleccione[campo3] != System.DBNull.Value)
                    Funcionario.Foto = (byte[])seleccione[campo3];
            }  
            seleccione.Close();  
       }
```

3º Método: Que comunica directamente com o banco de dados Código:

```
class clsABD
    {
        public SqlConnection conexao;
        private SqlCommand comando;
        private SqlCommandBuilder comandoB;
        private SqlDataAdapter seleccione;
        private SqlDataReader seleccione1;
        private DataTable tabela; 
        private string caminho = String.Format("Data Source=Dario;Initial Catalog=DB_EMPRESA;Integrated Security=True");
        public void LigarBD()
        {
            if (conexao != null)
                conexao.Close();
            try
            {
                conexao = new SqlConnection(caminho);
                conexao.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                throw new Exception ("Erro! Aplicação não conseguio ligar a Base de Dados!"+ex.Message);
            }  
        }
        public void DesligarBD()
        {
            try
            {
                conexao = new SqlConnection(caminho);
                conexao.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {      
                throw new Exception ("Erro ao tentar desligar a Base de Dados!"+ex.Message);
            }    
        }
        public void mExecutarComandos(string comandoSQL)
        {
            LigarBD();
            comando = new SqlCommand(comandoSQL,conexao);
            try
            {
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao executar camandoSQL!" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                DesligarBD();  
           }
        }
        public DataTable mCriarTabela(string comandoSQL)
        {
            LigarBD();
            tabela = new DataTable();
            seleccione = new SqlDataAdapter(comandoSQL,conexao);
            comandoB = new SqlCommandBuilder(seleccione);
            seleccione.Fill(tabela);
            DesligarBD();  
            return tabela; 
        }
        public SqlDataReader mCriarTabelaLeitura(string comandoSQL)
        {
            LigarBD();
            comando = new SqlCommand(comandoSQL, conexao);
            seleccione1  = comando.ExecuteReader();
            //DesligarBD(); 
            return seleccione1;  
        }
    }
```

Esta tudo em conforme, carrega todos campos menos o campo Fotografia na *PictureBox*, mas na hora de executar apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Parâmetro Invalido exatamente no método que converte o byte para
>   imagem.

**Observação:** Estou programando em 3 camadas

Comment: **Obs.:** Não use a tag `visual-studio` para problemas que não são relacionados com a IDE. Veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246) se tiver dúvidas.

Comment: relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94219/image-para-byte

Answer (score 5):

Você não precisa de tudo isso pra converter um array de `byte` para um objeto **`Image`**.

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] img) 
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(img))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
}
```

É importante não esquecer do `using` porque ele faz a chamada do `Dispose()` ao final da operação. Se o `Dispose` não for chamado, os recursos não serão liberados e a imagem ficará indisponível para outras operações.

Comment: Boa noite tentei utilizando as diversa maneiras apresentada mais mesmo assim não houve sucesso. Mas vou postar o código completo:

Answer (score 1):

Código de `array` de `bytes` (`byte[]`) para `Image`:

```
public Image ByteToImage(byte[] image)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
     return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

e esse código com a classe [ImageConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public Image ByteToImage(byte[] image)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(image);
}
```

---

Tem um [código completo e pronto](http://www.codigoexpresso.com.br/Home/Postagem/23).

***Referencias:***

- [C# Image to Byte Array and Byte Array to Image Converter Class](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15460/c-image-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-image-conv)
- [ImageConverter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Converter imagem para byte e de byte para imagem em C# (CSharp)](http://www.codigoexpresso.com.br/Home/Postagem/23)